# Как изменить значения input, где name='invest' и id='1'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пример кода:

```
<script>
  function test () {
    $("input[name='invest']").val('200');
  }
</script>

<button onclick='test()'>200</button>
<input id='1' name='invest' value='100'>
<input id='2' name='invest' value='100'>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы значения input изменилось только для поля id='1'?

Comment: Работать не с `name` а с `id`

Comment: Это упрощенный пример. На самом деле у меня таблица, где строка = class для inputa(ов), а каждое поле строки имеет уникальное название name.
Так что вариант только с id не подойдет

Comment: @vKs, спецификация HTML требует, чтобы каждый идентификатор (значение атрибута id) был **уникален** в пределах страницы. Как следствие, работать только с id это таки выход.

Comment: @vKs Вы понимаете, что упрощая пример вы тем самым искажаете суть, которую можно было решить каким-либо образом, а так в итоге у вас будет куча костылей? Лучше бы вы показали то, что у вас имеется и на нем экспериментировали. Вы когда в больницу к доктору идете не упрощаете же свои симптомы на которые жалуетесь?)) ... и уж тем более какого вы еще решения ждали бы при таких данных кроме как выборки по ИД?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если бы я мог показать свой код я бы его показал. Но на самом деле он намного сложнее и я не хочу тратить Ваше время на него. Поэтому упростил его.
И если невозможно изменить значение по 2 идентификаторам, в jQuery, то значит буду искать другой выход.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Спасибо, я это знаю, но для этого мне нужно будет изменить кучу кода. Но вижу что другого варианта не остается

Comment: @vKs Боюсь без вашего кода, над которым вы непосредственно работаете и к которому хотите применить решение, вам никто кроме выборки по ИД предложить не сможет в пределах предоставленного кода

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если бы была возможность написать код вот так $("input[name='invest', id='1']").val('200');, то тогда было бы и счастье, но видется, что прийдется сделать автоматическое генерирование id

Comment: @vKs, практически так и можно `$("input[name='invest'][id='1']").val('200');` но чем это отличается от выборки по id - я. честно говоря, не знаю

Comment: @Grundy Только тем, что мне не пришлось бы переделовать кучу кода))). А так спасибо, учту на будущее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНО! Как советовали выше, сделал изменения по идентификатору id

```
<script>
  function test () {
    $("#invest_1").val('200');
  }
</script>

<button onclick='test()'>200</button>
<input id='invest_1' name='invest' value='100'>
<input id='invest_2' name='invest' value='100'>
```

Comment: Вас же, вроде, это не устраивало.

Answer (score 1):

так бы выглядела выборка сразу по `id` и по `name`

```
$('input#1[name="invest"]').val('200');
```

но в случае, если у вас `id` неуникальный и есть несколько таких связок, то выбиралась бы только первая (исходя из соображений уникальности `id`). Так что этот код не рекомендую использовать.

Выборку лучше делать либо только по уникальному `id`

```
$('input#1').val('200');
```

либо, если обеспечить его уникальность задача не позволяет, использовать вместо него атрибут `class`, тогда выражение выглядело бы так

```
$('input.test_1[name="invest"]').val('200');
```

а поля так

```
<input class="test_1" name='invest' value='100'>
<input class='test_2' name='invest' value='100'>
<input class="test_1" name='other_field' value='100'>
<input class='test_2' name='other_field' value='100'>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже переделал id и у меня все поля получились с уникальным id.